# Windows Phone apps crash on startup

Tags: apps, store, lumia-650

Sometimes apps on my Lumia 650 will crash when started. Restarting the phone does not help, neither is it a problem with installing it on the SD card etc. Most of the time a reinstall cycle will work, but this will wipe the app's data. Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try a complete soft or a hard reset of the phone (that mostly helps here on my side, and these problems normally occur after an update like the Creators Update), but be sure to **backup your files etc. before**!

Comment: Even I had the same problem. The whole system was in a messed up state. But once after a hard reset, phone is working fine. As John Archer said, make sure to backup all your files and applications before a hard reset.

Comment: The problem will persist after a hard reset after some time. A hard reset is basically a reinstall cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the store page of said app, and click on "Launch" or "Install" from there. The app will then start normally.